# Is there an easy way to find specific x and y coordinates of a Pane I created

Tags: javafx

I created a Pane where I am trying to add shapes to specific x and y coordinates on this pane. Currently I am just putting the shapes in the middle of the pane and adjusting the coordinates slowly till the shape ends up where I want it. Is there a way I can see where the x and y coordinates are on the pane so I know exactly where to place the shapes.

Answer (score 1):

A `Pane` inherits from `Node` and therefore also inherits the `layoutXProperty` and `layoutYProperty`. So you can get the `Pane` coordinates by calling the appropriate methods on it:

```
int paneX = pane.getLayoutX();
int paneY = pane.getLayoutY();
```

These methods would be available for your shapes as well.

Comment: this return 0..